# Get form content by a click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, get, click

I'd like to get the value of an hidden input by clicking on a link.
Here is  my HTML forms(they are generated by a script so I copied here the generated html):

```
    <form method="POST" action="#" class="mButton" name="buttonSettings">

        <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="mController" />
        <input type="hidden" name="view" value="getProject" />
</form>

    <form method="POST" action="#" class="mButton" name="buttonProject">

        <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="mController" />
        <input type="hidden" name="view" value="getProject" />
</form>

    <!--  [...] 
An example of a link which is binding to a form
-->
    <a href="#" class="activity vtip" title="title" onclick="mButtonClick('buttonSettings');">Settings</a>
```

I tried several things but without success ..

javascript :

```
function mButtonClick(idButton)
{
    $("form[name="+idButton+"]").click(function ()
    {
        // test #1
        console.log($(this).contents().find("input[name=view]").val());
        // test #2
        console.log($("form[name="+idButton+"] input[name=view]").val());
    });
}
```

Whatever I test it return undefined ...
Ideas ?

edit

**how it works :**

-several forms on the page.

-all of it are binding to a link

-by clicking a link, the `mButtonClick(idButton)` function is called and should get values of the binding form.

the last step doesn't works.

Comment: your html form code looks weird. What are '+controller+' , '+id+' & '+view+' ?? Are you trying to build the form by script ?

Comment: actually yes, all forms are generated by a script

Comment: So, what if changing ".val()" into ".length" ? You could check if you've got the correct element. "undefined" value returning always relates to noelement inside JQuery element sets.

Comment: still "undefined" with ".length" . 

but I don't understand why `$("form[name="+idButton+"]")` return the correct form and `($("form[name="+idButton+"] input[name=view]")` return undefined ...

Comment: If you're using firefox, just press Ctrl+Shift+J , you'll see the javascript error(s). I think it's just structure issue.

Comment: i'm using chrome and i checked for js errors. everything it's ok. i see only the "undefined" from my console.log . to be sure, i tested also in FF : same results.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the button

you are also doing something extremely strange - are you binding it to the *form click*?

you should do something like

```
$('.mButton').click(function () {console.log($('form input[type="hidden"]').val())})
```

Comment: i need to get the input by its name

Comment: then use `input[name="name here"]` instead of "type=..."

Comment: because you have a mess in your code :) go and create simple fiddle at jsfiddle.net, then come back and post a link to it